# XAML "Add" navigation button

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

By default, in split page example there is a return button in the title panel. But I want to replace the return icon with an add icon. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: Show us what you are referencing. What example?

Comment: What in the world are you talking about?